# How might i add a watermark in a capture video in android/Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, watermark, video-recording

Here is my simple code basically I want to capture a video using the watermark without FFmpeg I want to do it in a simple way, please help

```
video_button.setOnClickListener {

        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE).also { takeVideoIntent ->
            takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
                startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
            }
```

Comment: AFAIK, there is nothing in Android for this. You would need to post-process the video, such as using the FFMpeg library that you cited. Or, add the watermark on your server.

Comment: @CommonsWare so can you please tell me how can I do it with simple code?

Comment: I have not researched how to use FFMpeg on Android. There are a number of sample apps and wrapper libraries [on the Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=ffmpeg), though.

Comment: can anyone please tell me the code how to do it with a simple manner I tried to use FFmpeg but the code is too confusing please help. Thanks

Comment: @CommonsWareI want to use --enable-libfreetype this library of FFmpeg in my project but I can't use it please help I search a lot about this but can't get the solution to please, please help